# Empty space above plot lines in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts (Highstock) to render a chart on my page.

I am specifying a max and min value for my axis, but despite this I end up with blank space above my graph:

[image: graph with blank space]

This is what my options look like currently:

```
var myChart = new Highcharts.Chart('container', {
    rangeSelector:{
        enabled: false
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true,
    },
    yAxis: [{
        opposite: false,
        title: {
            text: 'Gravity'
        },
        min: 1,
        max: items.options.gravity_max + 0.01
    },
    {
        opposite: true,
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (C)'
        },
        min: items.options.temperature_min - 1,
        max: items.options.temperature_max + 1
    }],
    navigator: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Temperature',
        data: items.temperature,
        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: true
        },
        yAxis: 1,
    }, {
        name: 'Gravity',
        data: items.specific_gravity,
        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: true
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'OG',
        data: items.original_gravity,
        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: true
        },
        dashStyle: 'dot',
        color: '#000'
    },
    {
        name: 'FG',
        data: items.final_gravity,
        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: true
        },
        dashStyle: 'dot',
        color: '#000'
    }]
});
```

Here is a link to a fiddle with a simplified version of the data; http://jsfiddle.net/3eLrn61w/

What is causing that blank space above, and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Highcharts by default will try to start and end an axis on a label. Your current max is `1.071+0.01` (`1.081`). This is more than the label checkpoint of `1.075`, which causes another label to be made.

You can fix this by doing ([JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3eLrn61w/2/)):

```
yAxis: [{
    // ...
    endOnTick: false
}]
```

A few other options you might want to evaluate is the matching `axis.startOnTick: false`, possibly `axis.maxPadding: 0` to avoid creating labels that are marginally needed and `chart.alignTicks: false` to free up the connection between the axis.

An alternative approach will also be to alter the tick positions (`axis.tickPositions` or `axis.tickPositioner`) so that they line up better with your min and max values.

Or your third option is to alter your handcoded maximum of the axis (`max: items.options.gravity_max + 0.01`), so that it does not create such a label gap, f.x. by being `max: 1.074`.

However, I think your best bet may be with the `startOnTick` and `endOnTick` options.

Comment: Great suggestions! It is looking much better now. I'm new to Highcharts, so still wrapping my head around all the configuration options and terminology.